# How to make jquery find the row and fire an action on success (using "this")

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this

This is a jquery code that performs a database update when the user modifies a cell:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('tr').on('blur', 'td[contenteditable]', function() {
        $.post("ajax/modQtyModels", {
            modelId: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.idmodel').text(),
            qty: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').text(),
            ajax: true,
            success: function(data) {
                $(this).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("success");
            }
       });
    });
});
```

In the "success" part I want it to just change the class (to change its color as it uses bootstrap) of that cell to show the user that their data changed successfully but it doesn't seem to notice that it has to change the color. I've tried everything on that line but I guess the line is not the problem. Other actions like an alert work well so I suspect of the $(this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `success` callback you are dealing with another `function`, so the `scope` is no longer the one of your `blur` event `callback`, so `this` keyword will point out to another `object` and not your jQuery element.

So you need to save the `this` value in another `variable` and refer to your element with this neww variable, inside the `success` callback.

```
(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').on('blur', 'td[contenteditable]', function() {
    var tr = $(this);
    $.post("ajax/modQtyModels", {
      modelId: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.idmodel').text(),
      qty: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').text(),
      ajax: true,
      success: function(data) {
        tr.closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("success");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside of `success: function(data) {` does not refer to `this` inside of `$('tr').on('blur'`

You can save the value of `this` (typically in a variable called `that`), so that when you are in that new function, you can do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('tr').on('blur', 'td[contenteditable]', function() {
        var that = this;
        $.post("ajax/modQtyModels", {
            modelId: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.idmodel').text(),
            qty: $(this).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').text(),
            ajax: true,
            success: function(data) {
                $(that).closest('tr').children('td.editQty').addClass("success");
            }
       });
    });
});
```